# What is the purpose of this CSS snippet?

Tags: html, css

I have the following snippet in my stylesheet. What is the impact or purpose?

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: to annoy the crap out of future developers.. Also top and left have no effect unless the item has a position other then static.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a [reset CSS](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/). It's purpose is to remove default non-zero spacings for all (`*`) elements. All browsers have some default style sheet and they're not very consistent with each other. Take `<form>` as an example.

**Note:** Setting the `left` and `top` properties to `0px` doesn't look right to me. It will most probably cause problems with absolute positioning. When positioning an element absolutely you may want to define only it's vertical or horizontal offset (not both), leaving the other offset unchanged. That reset CSS doesn't allow that because it gives values for both vertical and horizontal. Also you may want to position an element from the bottom. If you have that reset it will have both `bottom` and `top` which in most cases is not wanted and may alter the height of the element or not respect one of the offsets. In any case it will give you something not intended and break your layout.

For those who want to learn more: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#absolute-positioning

Comment: mentioning that 'resetting the left and top properties' was causing a on page problem in a google map control!  Removing them solved my problem (which is why I asked this question).  I'll vote it up and accept as answered.

Comment: I've clarified your last point. Feel free to rollback if you don't like it.

Answer (score 11):

It is a *reset*. All elements will have 0 margin, padding, etc. after that.

Such resets are useful to normalize behavior (some browsers come with predefined margins, paddings, etc.) and to increase visual consistency across browsers.

Comment: and their position is reset (though you won't see any difference with `position:relative;`)

Comment: @knittl, do you mean, position:relative will override the behaviour?  I have a google map control I'm loading on to a page and this snippet's impact breaks the layout inside the map.  If I remove the snippet, it renders properly.  However other page elements are misaligned.

Comment: @FiveTools It breaks the positioning for elements that have `position: absolute;` (see my answer). Google maps makes extensive use of absolute positioning.

Comment: @FiveTools: you won't see a difference with `relative` positioned elements, the default is `top:0; left:0;`, but you will see a difference with `absolute` positioned elements, they will stick in the top left corner (of their parent container, usually `body`, unless specified otherwise). also `*` is a very weak selector and should be overriden by anything that specifies position/top/left – it's just for resetting weird browser defaults

Answer (score 1):

It applies the rules contained within to all elements of the page; creating a predictible baseline for cascading rules.

The technique is called a "reset" (google for "CSS Reset") and is an approach to resolve different browsers using different default CSS rules.

These rules should applied as early as possible, typically at the start of the first-loaded CSS sheet.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of your snippet is to reset the margin, padding and set the position to the top-left corner of the viewport in your web-browser.

Answer (score 0):

The Estric simbol is known as all /everything so the meaning of this is the CSS will be implemented over all elemetns and set the values as parametered.